# Extract x-axis value using y-axis data in R

Tags: time-series, data-mining, missing-data, interpolation

I have a time-series dataset in this format:

```
       Time Val1 Val2
     0 0.68 0.39
    30 0.08 0.14
    35 0.12 0.07
    40 0.17 0.28
    45 0.35 0.31
    50 0.14 0.45
   100 1.01 1.31
   105 0.40 1.20
   110 2.02 0.57
   115 1.51 0.58
   130 1.32 2.01
```

Using this dataset I want to extract(not predict) Time at which FC1=1 and FC2=1. Here is a plot that I created with annotated points I would like to extract.

[image]

I am looking for a solution using or function to interpolate/intercept to extract values. For example, if I draw a straight line at fold change 1 (say in y-axis), I want to extract all the points on X-axis where the line intercepts.

Looking forward for suggestions and thanks in advance !

Comment: Would you define FC for the uninitiated? Fold change?

Comment: Yes, it is fold-change or fold-cut off or specifically in this assay its kind of time at which transcription initiates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `approxfun` to do interpolations and `uniroot` to find single roots (places where the line crosses).  You would need to run uniroot multiple times to find all the crossings, the `rle` function may help choose the starting points.

The FC values in your data never get close to 1 let alone cross it, so you must either have a lot more data than shown, or mean a different value.

If you can give more detail (possibly include a plot showing what you want) then we may be able to give more detailed help.

**Edit**

OK, here is some R code that finds where the lines cross:

```
con <- textConnection('           Time Val1 Val2
         0 0.68 0.39
        30 0.08 0.14
        35 0.12 0.07
        40 0.17 0.28
        45 0.35 0.31
        50 0.14 0.45
       100 1.01 1.31
       105 0.40 1.20
       110 2.02 0.57
       115 1.51 0.58
       130 1.32 2.01')

mydat <- read.table(con, header=TRUE)

with(mydat, {
    plot( Time, Val1, ylim=range(Val1,Val2), col='green', type='l' )
    lines(Time, Val2, col='blue')
})
abline(h=1, col='red')

afun1 <- approxfun( mydat$Time, mydat$Val1 - 1 )
afun2 <- approxfun( mydat$Time, mydat$Val2 - 1 )
points1 <- cumsum( rle(sign(mydat$Val1 - 1))$lengths )
points2 <- cumsum( rle(sign(mydat$Val2 - 1))$lengths )

xval1 <- numeric( length(points1) - 1 )
xval2 <- numeric( length(points2) - 1 )

for( i in seq_along(xval1) ) {
    tmp <- uniroot(afun1, mydat$Time[ points1[c(i, i+1)] ])
     xval1[i] <- tmp$root
}

for( i in seq_along(xval2) ) {
    tmp <- uniroot(afun2, mydat$Time[ points2[c(i, i+1)] ])
     xval2[i] <- tmp$root
}

abline( v=xval1, col='green' )
abline( v=xval2, col='blue')
```

Comment: Thanks Greg I have now provided correct data. Here is a plot using the data with annotations that I have added manually: http://postimage.org/image/x7qkax47b/ I want to extract value at the points highlighted with arrows.